# event.ctrlKey works in IE and Chrome but not Firefox on legendItemClick

Tags: javascript, firefox, highcharts

Built a feature that deselects all but the ctrl-clicked item.  It works fine in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox.
Try the jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/PJVK3/

Tried to capture the same event with simple javascript code and the same problem occurs.
This works in Chrome(24.0.1312.57) and IE(9), but not Firefox(18.0.2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
if (event.ctrlKey){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="ctl key pressed";}
if (!event.ctrlKey){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="ctl key NOT pressed";}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Whatup?  anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look the source code you'll see that it stores the event on `event.browserEvent`.
It's a fixed bug: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/pull/992

So, why you have to use `event.browserEvent` instead of `window.event` ?
Simple, because `window.event` doesn't exist in Firefox.

```
legendItemClick: function(e) {
    var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';

    if (!e.browserEvent.ctrlKey) {
        if (!confirm('The series is currently '+ 
            visibility +'. Do you want to change that?')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/u7p5r/)

**Source code** - *relevant code*:

```
.on('click', function (event) {
    var strLegendItemClick = 'legendItemClick',
        fnLegendItemClick = function () {
            item.setVisible();
        };

    // Pass over the click/touch event. #4.
    event = {
        browserEvent: event                  // < -- here is the magic
    };

    // click the name or symbol
    if (item.firePointEvent) { // point
        item.firePointEvent(strLegendItemClick, event, fnLegendItemClick);
    } else {
        fireEvent(item, strLegendItemClick, event, fnLegendItemClick);
    }
});
```

Comment: NICE find, you win. It's just weird that it only doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: You nailed it.  However, I do believe it was a bug.  It would not work on my local implementation since I host my own highcharts.js, because I need more colors than the standard pallete.  I had to download the latest version for things to start working correctly.  Thanks a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
                var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
                if (evtobj.shiftKey) {
                    //do something
                } else {
                   //other things
                }
```

This will work in Chrome, IE and firefox.